# How to make TomCat fail while it's running?

Tags: java, tomcat, windows-server

I have TomCat deployed on a Windows server for the purpose of hosting a Java application.  I just modified TomCat within the properties tab such that it will try to restart automatically if Tomcat fails.  How can I test this?  I want to make TomCat fail so I can see if the automatic restart works properly.

One such way is to cause it to run out of memory.  But I don't know how to do that.  Is there another way, or would someone be able to explain how to make Tomcat run out of memory?

Comment: Create a servlet that calls `System.exit(1)`. That'll kill Tomcat for sure. Or just kill the Tomcat process from the task manager (Windows) or `kill` command (Linux).

Comment: @Andreas, is killing the Tomcat process from Taskmanager the same thing as going under the Services tab within Taskmanager, right clicking the process, and selecting "Stop"?  I think the answer to my question is "no", but I don't see any "Kill" switch within task manager for any service.

Comment: No, because using service stop is a controlled stop, and doesn't trigger "failure restart" *(if it did you could never stop the service, right?)*.

Comment: Right-click the process and "end" or "kill" it.

Comment: I ended up manually killing TomCat with the "taskkill" command in the command line.  It did not restart the service automatically like I configured it to within the Recovery tab.  Perhaps killing it that way is not the same as making TomCat fail?